# What is rendering?

Tags: rendering

So I’m new to blender and I don’t understand rendering 
When do I do it? What does it do?
I’ve tried looking around but I couldn’t find the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I don't think you actually put in the effort to search as a simple google search will get you a ton of answers. Here is the rendering section of the blender manual. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Rendering is a complex and vast area. 
Anyway, to put it easily and in a few words, it is the process during which an image (an output) is produced by a calculator (a computer) through a series of physical, geometrical and mathematical parameters (some inputs). These parameters consist in shapes (2d/3d models), materials and lighting conditions and are determined by the user/artist inside a environment like Blender. Finally, the rendering engine (like Cycles) does the math and gives you the final image.

This is a generic definition but you can start looking up to some basic and more accurate knowlege on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_(computer_graphics)

Hope I made myself clear.

Happy learning!

Cheers!